# How to add MySQL foreach loop to DOMDocument XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, domdocument

Here is what I have come up with, and it appears to work for returning one record, however if there is more than one record (wp_hud_display.id) in the database it breaks the XML, would "foreach" work in the while loop? and how would I add it to my code?

```
<?php    
// create a dom document with encoding utf8 
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "root";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "";
$config['db_name']    = "tasmanhud";

//connect to host
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);

//select database
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

//select all items in table
$sql = "SELECT
  wp_hud_display.id,
  wp_hud_display.name,
  wp_hud_display.resolution,
  wp_hud_display.user_id,
  wp_hud_display.instrument_id_1,
  wp_hud_display.x_loc_1,
  wp_hud_display.y_loc_1,
  wp_hud_display.layer_1,
  wp_hud_display.instrument_id_2,
  wp_hud_display.x_loc_2,
  wp_hud_display.y_loc_2,
  wp_hud_display.layer_2,
  wp_hud_display.instrument_id_3,
  wp_hud_display.x_loc_3,
  wp_hud_display.y_loc_3,
  wp_hud_display.layer_3,
  wp_hud_display.instrument_id_4,
  wp_hud_display.x_loc_4,
  wp_hud_display.y_loc_4,
  wp_hud_display.layer_4,
  wp_hud_instrument.inst_id AS inst1_id,
  wp_hud_instrument.name AS inst1_name,
  wp_hud_instrument.image_file AS inst1_image,
  wp_hud_instrument.font_type AS inst1_ft,
  wp_hud_instrument.font_size AS inst1_fs,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.inst_id AS inst2_id,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.name AS inst2_name,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.image_file AS inst2_image,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.font_type AS inst2_ft,
  wp_hud_instrument_1.font_size AS inst2_fs,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.inst_id AS inst3_id,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.name AS inst3_name,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.image_file AS inst3_image,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.font_type AS inst3_ft,
  wp_hud_instrument_2.font_size AS inst3_fs,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.inst_id AS inst4_id,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.name AS inst4_name,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.image_file AS inst4_image,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.font_type AS inst4_ft,
  wp_hud_instrument_3.font_size AS inst4_fs
FROM wp_hud_display
  LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument
    ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_1 = wp_hud_instrument.inst_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_1
    ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_2 = wp_hud_instrument_1.inst_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_2
    ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_3 = wp_hud_instrument_2.inst_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_hud_instrument wp_hud_instrument_3
    ON wp_hud_display.instrument_id_4 = wp_hud_instrument_3.inst_id
WHERE wp_hud_display.user_id = 1
GROUP BY wp_hud_display.id";

/* create the root element of the xml tree */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("wp_hud_displays");
/* append it to the document created */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

$hud_display_group = $domtree->createElement("hud_display_group");
$hud_display_group = $xmlRoot->appendChild($hud_display_group);

$hud_display = $domtree->createElement("hud_display");
$hud_display = $hud_display_group->appendChild($hud_display);

$instrument_id_1 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_1");
$instrument_id_1 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_1);

$instrument_id_2 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_2");
$instrument_id_2 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_2);

$instrument_id_3 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_3");
$instrument_id_3 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_3);

$instrument_id_4 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_4");
$instrument_id_4 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_4);

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
       while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
       {

    /* you should enclose the following two lines in a cicle */

$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('id',$result_array['id']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['name']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('resolution',$result_array['resolution']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('user_id',$result_array['user_id']));

// Instrument 1
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_1',$result_array['instrument_id_1']));
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst1_id']));
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst1_name']));
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst1_image']));
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst1_ft']));  
$instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst1_fs']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_1',$result_array['x_loc_1']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_1',$result_array['y_loc_1']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_1',$result_array['layer_1']));

// Instrument 2
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_2',$result_array['instrument_id_2']));
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst2_id']));
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst2_name']));
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst2_image']));
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst2_ft']));  
$instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst2_fs']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_2',$result_array['x_loc_2']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_2',$result_array['y_loc_2']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_2',$result_array['layer_2']));

// Instrument 3 
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_3',$result_array['instrument_id_3']));
    $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst3_id']));       $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst3_name']));
$instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst3_image']));
$instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst3_ft']));  $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst3_fs']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_3',$result_array['x_loc_3']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_3',$result_array['y_loc_3']));
$hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_3',$result_array['layer_3']));



    // Instrument 4
 $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_4',$result_array['instrument_id_4']));
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst4_id']));
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst4_name']));
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst4_image']));
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst4_ft']));  
    $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst4_fs'])); $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_4',$result_array['x_loc_4']));
    $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_4',$result_array['y_loc_4']));
    $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_4',$result_array['layer_4']));

            }
        }
    // get the xml printed 

       echo $domtree->saveXML();



        //send the xml header to the browser

    header ("Content-Type:text/xml");


        //output the XML data

    echo $xml;
    ?>
```

This is how it displays when there is only one set of values to return (wp_hud_display.id)

```
<wp_hud_displays>
     <hud_display_group>
       <hud_display>
         <instrument_id_1></instrument_id_1>
         <instrument_id_2></instrument_id_2>
         <instrument_id_3></instrument_id_3>
         <instrument_id_4></instrument_id_4>
       <id>1</id>
       <name>test display</name>
       <resolution>1080p</resolution>
       <user_id>1</user_id>
       <instrument_id_1>1</instrument_id_1>
       <x_loc_1>89</x_loc_1>
       <y_loc_1>79</y_loc_1>
       <layer_1>1</layer_1>
       <instrument_id_2>2</instrument_id_2>
       <x_loc_2>988</x_loc_2>
       <y_loc_2>98</y_loc_2>
       <layer_2>1</layer_2>
       <instrument_id_3>3</instrument_id_3>
       <x_loc_3>89</x_loc_3>
       <y_loc_3>90</y_loc_3>
       <layer_3>1</layer_3>
       <instrument_id_4>4</instrument_id_4>
       <x_loc_4>67</x_loc_4>
       <y_loc_4>76</y_loc_4>
       <layer_4>1</layer_4>
      </hud_display>
     </hud_display_group>
    </wp_hud_displays>
```

How it displays when there is more than one wp_hud_display.id WHERE user_id=1

```
1test1_gauge001-2_zpsdbe86ca1f.jpg11PID_DISTANCE30100002500101223dfd34412sdf34534056Arail122test1_needle11PID_ENGINE_LOAD211000025200160112025000000002test1_needle11PID_ENGINE_LOAD211000025200160112025000000003new gaugedfsgsdfgfd435430PID_COOLANT_TEMP2434534541023324000000003new gaugedfsgsdfgfd435430PID_COOLANT_TEMP2434534541023324000000004Bla100.jpg2702334395910299000000004Bla100.jpg2702334395910299000000002test1_needle11PID_ENGINE_LOAD211000025200160112025000000001test display1080p118979129889813899014677612dsfdsfsd720p12321342323213224232123143423444342
```

What I am after is it to appear like proper XML output (like the first example) no matter how many sets of records it returns.

Comment: Why not. Give it a try

Comment: You can do this using a for loop too: for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {}, Please upload an example of the finished xml that are you traying to do.

Comment: More information added to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the hud_display node repeats, then include inside the while, for each iteration a new hud_display will be created. Something like this have to work:

```
    // create a dom document with encoding utf8 
    $domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    //database configuration and extract your data

    /* create the root element of the xml tree */
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("wp_hud_displays");
    /* append it to the document created */
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

    $hud_display_group = $domtree->createElement("hud_display_group");
    $hud_display_group = $xmlRoot->appendChild($hud_display_group);

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
       while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
            $hud_display = $domtree->createElement("hud_display");
            $hud_display = $hud_display_group->appendChild($hud_display);

            $instrument_id_1 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_1");
            $instrument_id_1 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_1);

            $instrument_id_2 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_2");
            $instrument_id_2 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_2);

            $instrument_id_3 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_3");
            $instrument_id_3 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_3);

            $instrument_id_4 = $domtree->createElement("instrument_id_4");
            $instrument_id_4 = $hud_display->appendChild($instrument_id_4);

            /* you should enclose the following two lines in a cicle */

            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('id',$result_array['id']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['name']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('resolution',$result_array['resolution']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('user_id',$result_array['user_id']));

            // Instrument 1
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_1',$result_array['instrument_id_1']));
            $instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst1_id']));
            $instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst1_name']));
            $instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst1_image']));
            $instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst1_ft']));  
            $instrument_id_1->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst1_fs']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_1',$result_array['x_loc_1']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_1',$result_array['y_loc_1']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_1',$result_array['layer_1']));

            // Instrument 2
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_2',$result_array['instrument_id_2']));
            $instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst2_id']));
            $instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst2_name']));
            $instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst2_image']));
            $instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst2_ft']));  
            $instrument_id_2->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst2_fs']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_2',$result_array['x_loc_2']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_2',$result_array['y_loc_2']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_2',$result_array['layer_2']));

            // Instrument 3 
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_3',$result_array['instrument_id_3']));
            $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst3_id']));       
            $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst3_name']));
            $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst3_image']));
            $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst3_ft']));  
            $instrument_id_3->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst3_fs']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_3',$result_array['x_loc_3']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_3',$result_array['y_loc_3']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_3',$result_array['layer_3']));

            // Instrument 4
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('instrument_id_4',$result_array['instrument_id_4']));
            $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('inst_id',$result_array['inst4_id']));
            $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name',$result_array['inst4_name']));
            $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('image_name',$result_array['inst4_image']));
            $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_type',$result_array['inst4_ft']));  
            $instrument_id_4->appendChild($domtree->createElement('font_size',$result_array['inst4_fs'])); 
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('x_loc_4',$result_array['x_loc_4']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('y_loc_4',$result_array['y_loc_4']));
            $hud_display->appendChild($domtree->createElement('layer_4',$result_array['layer_4']));

        }
    }
// get the xml printed 
echo $domtree->saveXML();

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

//output the XML data
echo $xml;
```

Comment: Thanks user1977204, I tried your surgestions for including HUD nodes inside the loop, but it stays the same, returns one set of "wp_hud_display.id" works perfectly, but drops the XML formatting when returning more than one set.

I also tried adding the "for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++){" after and before the "while" line in the loop, and this didn't appear to resolve the problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you an error when more than one set is fetched from the database? Check the logs, but if the echo always print one set of the mysql query, then maybe there is one row only, debug your query for validate that more than one row is fetched. Also the last line echo $xml; isn't doing anything, the $xml variable is never used.

Comment: There is two sets in the database, with the "WHERE wp_hud_display.user_id = 1" in the SQL query selecting the required sets, I'm changing it in the database so it returns two sets, that's when it drops the formatting. and outputs the result with BOTH sets of results displayed on the page.
I then change user_id for one of the sets to a different value and it works perfectly, displaying the result in XML formatting.

Comment: Ok, there is an error with the query when you touch the database, but I thing the title of this post doesn't reference your problem. The answer above reflect the xml you wanted in a while loop, if you have antoher problem, post another question and put more info about that.

Comment: ok, would it be best to define the problem as "more than one MySQL result drops XML formatting"?
For reposting the question, enorder to make it easyier to resolve